# Stoping URL Routing from happening on certain directorys and anything it contains, including sub-directorys

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing, .net-4.5

I am using URL Routing for my application and would like to prevent URL Routing from happening on any thing starting with staff/ but using the following code it does not work, how can I get ASP.Net to prevent URL Routing from touching the staff dir and it's sub dirs?

```
    private static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection Routes)
{
    //URLs to ignore routeing on
    RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("staff/");

    //Good routes
    Routes.MapPageRoute("Reviews", "{Category}/{RouteName}/Reviews.aspx", "~/RouteFiles/Reviews.aspx");
    Routes.MapPageRoute("Races", "{Category}/{RouteName}/Races.aspx", "~/RouteFiles/Races.aspx");
    Routes.MapPageRoute("SectionHomePage", "{Category}/{RouteName}", "~/RouteFiles/SectionHomePage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make an `RouteTable.Routes.Ignore()` entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebForms and not MVC, which I assume, try using [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler.aspx):

```
routes.Add(new Route("staff/", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Using `Routes.Ignore` may work in MVC (not sure about that), but it does not work in a WebForms application.

By assigning the StopRoutingHandler as the default handler for this path, you basically tell the application that all request should be handled by this Handler, which blocks all following attempts to route within this directory.

Comment: Addingt hat did not prevent it from doing routing on the URL staff/elmah.axd I know doing Route.Ignore does work in WebForms since RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("staff/elmah.axd"); does prevent routing from runing on that URL.